# Show $A$ is closed in $(C([a, b]), d_u)$, where $A := [{f \in C([a, b]) : f} $ is L-Lipschitz continuous].

Tags: real-analysis

Fix $L > 0$ and consider that

$A := [{f \in C([a, b]) : f} $ is L-Lipschitz continuous].

Show $A$ is closed in $(C([a, b]), d_u)$.

I know that if it is Lipschitz continuous, then $d_Y (f(x), f(x
0)) ≤ Ld_X(x, x')$ . But I still don't know how to do this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your space is normed, with the sup norm, since $[a,b]$ is compact. In particular, closure is equivalent to sequential closure. So it is enough to prove that if $f_n \in C([a,b]$ is a uniformly convergent sequence of $L$-Lipschitz functions, then $f$ is also $L$-Lipschitz.

But for this, we have $$|f(x) - f(y)| = |f(x) - f_n(x) + f_n(x) - f_n(y) + f_n(y) - f(y)| \leq |f(x) - f_n(x)| + |f_n(x) - f_n(y)| + |f_n(y) - f(y)|$$

by using the triangle inequality repeatedly.

But the first and last terms can be made arbitrarily small by uniform convergence, so we have further that

$$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq 2 \epsilon + |f_n(x) - f_n(y)| = 2 \epsilon + L|x-y|$$

as we are assuming the $f_n$ are $L$-Lipschitz. Now send $\epsilon \to 0$ and we're done.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. I took $n$ large enough so that those differences are both less than $\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we can send it to $0$.

Comment: That works! Thank you!

Comment: Feel free to upvote/accept the answer if you feel it best :)